# TYK Gateway - transform query parameters from camelCase to snake_case

Tags: tyk

how to transform query parameters from camelCase to snake_case in TYK Gateway?

For example,
`https://gateway.com?firstName=John&lastName=Doe`
to
`https://upstream.com?first_name=John&last_name=Doe`

Comment: I think this has been answered in the Tyk forum: https://community.tyk.io/t/how-to-transform-query-parameters-from-camelcase-to-snake-case/6027

Answer (score 1):

I think you could achieve your goal with a [custom plugin](https://tyk.io/docs/plugins/). There isn't an inbuilt middleware that allows you to transform the query parameters to your desired result.

The code for your plugin would be in the [Request lifecycle](https://tyk.io/docs/plugins/request-plugins/) and would take advantage of the [request object](https://tyk.io/docs/plugins/supported-languages/javascript-middleware/middleware-scripting-guide/#the-request-object). There are a [few examples](https://github.com/TykTechnologies/custom-plugin-examples) that can get you started on using custom plugins